# Julia Universal Comparison Operator

Tags: julia, operators

I usually use Crystal when I write my code. In Crystal, there is the `<=>` comparison operator. Usage is simple:

```
p! 404 <=> 405
```

This would print the following in my terminal:

```
404 <=> 405 # => -1
```

The printed value is `-1`, but if the integers in the equation were switched, it would print `1`, as 405 is greater than 404. If the integers were equal, it would print `0`.

I would like to use something similar in a Julia program I am writing, but can't seem to find an operator that works. I can of course use if-else if-else logic but I am really only concerned with storing the value in a database.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want?

```
julia> cmp(404, 405)
-1

julia> cmp(404, 404)
0

julia> cmp(405, 404)
1
```

Comment: I didn't know about `cmp` and was trying `sign(x - y)`. So I compared them after I saw your answer: somehow, `sign(x - y)` is many times faster than `cmp(x, y)`. Maybe there's some subtlety (either in functionality or in the benchmarking) that I'm missing though. I'll post my (pretty simple) code in the next comment:

Comment: `A = rand(10000);
B = rand(10000); 
@btime [cmp(a, b) for (a, b) in Iterators.zip(A, B)];
@btime [sign(a - b) for (a, b) in Iterators.zip(A, B)];
` 
`cmp` took `122.080 μs `, while `sign` took `18.344 μs `
The first

Comment: This has already been fixed as of 1.7. `cmp` uses `isless` while `sign` uses `<`. `isless` was made a bunch faster for 1.7

Comment: With 1.7 on my computer, I'm seeing 6 microseconds for both

Comment: The timing of these are issues with the Julia compiler (not generating optimal code in both cases - this comment is for Julia 1.6). Faster are just `cmp.(A, B)` and `sign.(A .- B)`. Still `sign` is a bit faster (not by much). Note that the `sign` approach is not equivalent to `cmp` for floats. Consider eg. `a=NaN` and `b=0.0` or `a=-0.0` and `b=0.0`.

Comment: @OscarSmith and Bogumił Thanks, that was illuminating.

Comment: To me this seems like an issue with comprehensions, not with `cmp` as such. `cmp.(A, B)` is _much_ faster than `[cmp(a, b) for (a, b) in Iterators.zip(A, B)]`. It's also much nicer. BTW: `zip` is available directly in Base, no need for the `Iterators`-prefix

Comment: This is what I have meant (under 1.6.3, not tested on 1.7). Still under 1.6.3 `cmp(x,y)` is a bit slower than `sign(x-y)`, but not by much.

Comment: @DNF Yeah, I noticed broadcast was faster, but used the comprehension to have equivalent code - `sign.(A .- B)` has two broadcasts and presumably an allocation for the intermediate vector `A .- B` that `cmp` doesn't, so that wouldn't be comparing the functions themselves. Thanks for the `zip` tip btw, gotta go look for what else `Base` reexports now!

Comment: No, the broadcasts fuse, so there are no extra intermediates. Broadcasting is awesome.

Comment: You should read this: https://julialang.org/blog/2017/01/moredots/